# How to display multiple user text-fields depending on user input?

Tags: php, html, forms

I need to display `<input type="text">` depending on the number given by the user in an html form.

If the user enters the number 3, it should display 3 text input fields for data entry. Is it possible for each to have different names for the inputs?

```
<form>
  <input type="number" name="numberOfTextFields" id="numberOfTextFields" onkeyup="generateTextfields($(this).val())"/>
  <div id="containerForTextFields"></div>
</form>
<script type="text/javascript">
  //jQuery already loaded
  var generateTextfields(number) {
    for(i = 0; i < number; i++) {
      $('#containerForTextFields').append('<input type="text" name="textField' + i + '"/>')
    }
  }
</script>
```

Comment: Hi! Welcome to Stackoverflow! please try to read [mcve] to learn how to ask in stackoverflow, at least you have to post your code.

Answer (score 0):

You need a [for loop](http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_looping_for.asp), basically:

```
for ($x = 0; $x <= $user_entered_number; $x++) {
    echo "<input type=\"text\">";
}
```